# invalid continuation byte in a multiprocessing Consumer

Tags: python, unicode, multiprocessing

I am opening some cosumers to multiprocess some tasks in python.
Sometimes, I cannot figure out under which conditions, I get an error like this:

> Process Consumer-9: Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "/usr/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/process.py", line 258, in
>   _bootstrap
>       self.run() File "/home/fon/workspace/acopuzzle/consumer.py", line 26, in run
>       next_task = self.task_queue.get() File "/usr/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/queues.py", line 117, in get
>       res = self._recv()
>
> UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position
>   26154714: invalid continuation byte

So basically is in this line in /usr/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/queues.py

```
self._recv = self._reader.recv
```

The method run of Consumer class is this one:

```
def run(self):
    proc_name = self.name

    while True:

        next_task = self.task_queue.get() # <-- Here is the error

        if next_task is None:
            self.task_queue.task_done()
            break

        answer = next_task()
        self.task_queue.task_done()
        self.result_queue.put(answer)

    return
```

Have you experienced anything similar and could you point me in a good direction?. Thanks

Comment: Fix your encoding configurations and/or locales?

Comment: my problem was that I was running out of RAM memory, fixed that a long time ago